# Cant delete .minecraft folder for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just downloaded Minecraft. When I pushed play, it finished, but then it loaded again. So I tried to delete the .minecraft folder, but it said the file is open in another program.

Comment: Did you still have the minecraft launcher open when you tried to delete the folder?

Comment: Open task manager, find javaw.exe under processes, right click it and click end process tree. Retry deleting the .minecraft folder.

Answer (score 10):

Restart your computer. This should stop the process that is using the .minecraft folder so you can delete it.

Answer (score 4):

Close completely every minecraft related program, then retry. You can't delete something if its data is being used by something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open an elevated cmd (run as administrator)
2. In the command prompt, type `list volume` and press Enter.

   This will let you see what the drive letter is for the drive that you want to delete the folder in since it may not always be the same drive letter that it is in Windows.
3. After making note of the drive letter, type `exit` and press Enter.
4. In the command prompt, type the command below and press Enter.

   ```
   RD /S /Q "Full Path of Folder"
   ```

   <sup>Substitute `Full Path of Folder` within quotes below with your folder's full path within quotes instead.</sup>

   For example, if I wanted to delete a folder named Folder on my desktop, I would type this command below.

   ```
   RD /S /Q "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Folder"
   ```
5. The folder should now be deleted. Close the command prompt.

   If you used a command prompt at boot, then also close the System Recovery Options window and restart the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, go to the command prompt (search `cmd` in the start menu) and then run the command:

```
taskkill /im javaw.exe
```

If it says "terminated process" then you're done. Go back and try to delete it, it should let you. However if it says it failed, then run:

```
taskkill /im javaw.exe /f
```

This will force quit Minecraft and there is no way it can fail. Now go to the folder and delete it.

Answer (score -1):

I use this [software](http://filehippo.com/en/download_unlocker) to delete these kinda "Hard-to-Delete" files.

Just right click on the file and select its option. You can then either kill the process using it, or move the file, or have it deleted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Click on the `.minecraft` folder, then `Shift+Del` when it says that the program is running, ignore all of those. After that, most of the files will be deleted. Shut down your computer, then go back to all those files and delete the remaining files in `.minecraft`. Then Minecraft should be fully deleted.

Comment: You can't just "ignore" a file being open in another folder. You can't open these at all, even with administrator access all programs will fail, the only way is to terminate the process (maybe forcefully)